# Double data amount when joining multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

**Link to all my database tables in excel format:**
[Database](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18NeMZ2y_W069hIwpsfImGuPzhkp-vVlP)

**This is the assignment I was tasked with:**
*Find total deposit, total withdraw, and total difference for each customer.*

**What I did was**

```
select c.customerid, customername, sum(d.depositamount) as 'Total Deposit', sum(w.withdrawalamount) as 'Total Withdraw', sum(d.depositamount) - sum(w.withdrawalamount) as 'differences'
from customers c left outer join deposits d on c.customerid = d.customerid 
left outer join withdrawals w on c.CustomerID = w.CustomerID 
group by c.CustomerID 
order by c.CustomerID;
```

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxExL.png)

[image]

My problem is that the "Total Deposit" and "Total Withdraw" have its data doubled. Since these two column data are doubled, the differences is also doubled. I know I can divide by 2 to all the column to solve the problem but I would like to know a proper method in doing this.

My question is how do I join multiple tables in such a way that the data will not be doubled?

(For example, "James Carlton Brokeridge" is suppose to have 450, 380, and 70 repsectively).

Comment: Unless the question relates to excel, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting incorrect values because every time a customer makes more than one deposit or withdrawal, that causes the rows in the other (withdrawal/deposit) table to be replicated when the two tables are joined. To work around this, do the sums in subqueries:

```
select c.customerid, 
       c.customername, 
       d.totaldeposit as 'Total Deposit', 
       w.totalwithdrawal as 'Total Withdraw', 
       d.totaldeposit - w.totalwithdrawal as 'differences'
from customers c 
left outer join (
   select customerid, sum(depositamount) as totaldeposit
   from deposits
   group by customerid
) d on c.customerid = d.customerid 
left outer join (
   select customerid, sum(withdrawalamount) as totalwithdrawal
   from withdrawals
   group by customerid
) w on c.customerid = w.customerid 
order by c.customerid
```